# Can prepositions take raised objects in English?

Tags: prepositions, raising

In English, some verbs are said to take raised objects as in:

> *I believe **you** to be seriously mistaken.*

Here, the verb *believe* takes ***you*** as a raised object.

Can the same be said about prepositions?

In English, can a preposition take a raised object?

If so, please give me some examples.

Comment: *I count on him to be seriously mistaken.*

Comment: That's not a preposition governing Raising -- that's the verb _count on_, which requires a preposition for its direct object; it passes all the tests for Raising, e.g, _He's counting on it to be a dark and stormy night_.

Comment: @jlawler Is there a preposition that 'governs' Raising?

Comment: No. Raising is governed by certain verbs only. [Details here.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)

Comment: @jlawler How about this 'with'? _With it being a dark and stormy night, I'll just stay home._

Comment: Why would you call that Raising? The object of _with_ is the gerund complement clause _it being a dark and stormy night_. Raising moves the subject of a subordinate clause to be a subject or object of an upstairs verb by separating it from its clause. _It_ is just the first word of the clause; it's not separated or moved.

Comment: @jlawler The question might be how to know whether _it being a dark and stormy night_ is a clause or not in the first place. Is the assessment that _being_ is a gerund a sufficient condition for concluding that _it being a dark and stormy night_ is a clause?

Comment: I don't think so.  The problem with some of the above examples is, imo, that the preposition-like word ("on", "with", "for") doesn't really seem to be a preposition, though it resembles one.

Comment: @GregLee What do you mean they "don't seem to be" prepositions?

Comment: @JK2, The preposition "on" has a spatial sense involving a surface, for instance, but there is nothing like that in the sense of "count on".  And real prepositions go together with a following NP to make a constituent, but can you get "On what is he counting?"?

Comment: @GregLee Then, what about 'with'?

Comment: The "with" that precedes the subject of an absolute construction is just a conventional way of marking such a construction.  Why think it's a preposition?  And if it were, why should the following logical subject optionally occur as a possessive instead of an accusative? ("With his being so stubborn, ...")

Comment: @GregLee How about this example? _We set off again, the Rover going precariously slowly in very low gear up hills, **with me staying on its tail** in case it petered out altogether._ Do you think it can be _... **with my staying on its tail**..._?

Comment: No, I don't think it can be "with my staying on its tail", And in your example, a locative "there" could be thrown in: "with me there staying on its tail",  That's a very interesting example.

Comment: @GregLee Why is it that 'my' is impossible there but 'his' is possible in your example ("With his being so stubborn, ...")? Also, isn't _me_ in _me staying on its tail_ a raised object of 'with'?

Comment: @JK2, I don't think your example is an absolute construction (if it were, "his" would be okay). Maybe it does have a raised object.  But I don't really understand your example. "staying on its tail" might be a reduced adverbial.

Comment: @GregLee Do you mean if it were an absolute construction 'with my staying on its tail' would be okay? As far as I know, in order for that to be an absolute construction, you should not have 'with'. I don't understand how a PP can ever be an absolute construction. That said, 'my' example is actually from CGEL, and I have posted a question at EL&U, in case you're interested: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488017/with-without-possessive-accusative-v-ing

Comment: @GregLee Also, do you think "its" is possible in my earlier example? _With **its** being a dark and stormy night, I'll just stay home._

Comment: @JK2, yes, I think that a possessive subject is possible in absolute constructions. I don't know that the "with" of an absolute construction is a preposition. Yes, I think "its" is possible in the earlier example.

Comment: @GregLee Sorry about this belated additional question, but I'd appreciate it if you could reply. What if I change the CGEL example like this? _The Rover went precariously slowly in very low gear up hills, with **me** staying on its tail in case it petered out altogether._ Here, would _**me**_ still be impossible to be replaced with _**my**_?

Comment: @JK2, Both "me" and "my" sound okay to me.  I'm not sure they mean quite the same thing.  With "me", the absolute construction expresses an accompanying circumstance.  With "my", it seems to be an explanation of some sort. (If I hadn't been staying on its tail, it might not have made it up those hills.)

Comment: @GregLee Then, why do you think "my" is not okay in the original example? _We set off again, the Rover going precariously slowly in very low gear up hills, with **my** staying on its tail in case it petered out altogether._ I mean, why can't this be interpreted as "an explanation of some sort"?

Comment: @JK2, I don't know.  But I've reviewed the earlier example, and my own judgment remains as it was.